# How to get next or previous selected item in CollectionView Grouping?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView with Item source and selected items bound to my view model. I am having trouble finding a way to click my next button and have the selected item in the list increment. This would not be an issue when binding to a regular collection, but when binding to a grouping object I cannot figure out how to do it.

So basically I need to figure out what the item after the selected item is in ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, QuestionBase>>(); Almost like flattening the group to see whats next.

```
//Where it gets bound in the view.    
     
 <CollectionView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedQuestions}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuestion, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  IsGrouped="True" SelectionMode="Single" >
    

 
//The object used to make the grouping: 
        
      public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
        {
            public K Key { get; private set; }
        
            public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
            {
                Key = key;
                foreach (var item in items)
                    this.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

//How the grouping object gets created.   
        
   GroupedQuestions = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, QuestionBase>>();
        GroupedQuestions.Add(new Grouping<string, QuestionBase>("Group 1", _questions));
        GroupedQuestions.Add(new Grouping<string, QuestionBase>("Group 2", _questions2));
        GroupedQuestions.Add(new Grouping<string, QuestionBase>("Group 3", _questions3));
```

Comment: how are you doing it for non-grouped collections?  The logic should be the same, except that you will need to find the correct group first, and will also have to deal with an item that is the first/last in a grouping